# Get method object with method references

Tags: java-8, method-reference

Is it possible to get an instance of `java.lang.reflect.Method` by using the new method reference feature of Java 8?

That way I would have a compile time check and refactoring would be also easier. Also, I wouldn't need to catch the exceptions (which shouldn't been thrown after all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

You will get a lambda of that method, not a `java.lang.reflect.Method`. You do not know the name of the method. Just as you can not have a reference to a "property" of a java bean. 
You can have a reference to the getter or setter but that is also a lambda and you do not know the actual name. 
In any case you'd have to provide the name as a String and that can't be checked by the compiler. I also tried this but failed. It simply can't be done unless you write something that checks the javacode/bytecode. But there are tools that do that. 
Maybe the Criteria API could be used for that, but it depends on the requirements.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html
There you'd have a `SingularAttribute` or similar field on a "metamodel" and then the regular java compiler can check the (generic) type of it.